# Wordpress Multisite Siteurl & css and images path?

Tags: wordpress

I have created two sub-domains under one main domain but the path of css, images, js etc in sub-domains are coming from main root and not from sub-domain.

How do I make the paths come from the sub-domain?

Comment: In the OPs defense, the question got edited out.

Comment: That's a bit complex matter. You should take some steps to debug it. Follow the Multisite 110 link in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/multisite/info

Comment: You could try installing this on your subdomains: https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/